# Python: elegant multi-line string formatting

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am using a database interface that takes the query string as the `key` argument of the `__getitem__()` method. For complex queries that is not very readable though:

```
e = db["(col1 in ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']) & ((col2 != {}) & (col3 != {})) & (col4 == 'something')".format(-some_value-1, -another_value-1)]
```

Currently I am using the following :

```
e = db[" & ".join([
       "(col1 in ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'])",
       "((col2 != {})".format(-some_value-1), 
       " (col3 != {}))".format(-another_value-1), 
       "(col4 == 'something')"
       ])]
```

I am looking for a more elegant (read: more easily readable) way of formatting this multiline string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more readable.

```
e = db["(col1 in ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']) & " +
       "((col2 != {}) & ".format(-some_value-1) +
       "(col3 != {})) & ".format(-another_value-1) +
       "(col4 == 'something')"]
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this looks batter just in case :)

```
e = db[
        """
        (col1 in ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'])
        & ((col2 != {}) & (col3 != {}))
        & (col4 == 'something')
        """.format(-some_value-1, -another_value-1)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e = db["(col1 in ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'])" +
       "& ((col2 != {}) & (col3 != {}))".format(-some_value-1, -another_value-1) +
       "& (col4 == 'something')"]
```

Comment: When you concatenate you'll have `a& b` instead of `a & b`. You should add a space before the first and third ampersand.

Comment: You think the database will care?

Comment: This *is* a question about elegance after all

Comment: And the code is more elegant without useless spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
db[" & ".join(("(col1 in ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'])",
               "((col2 != {col2_neq})",
               "(col3 != {col3_neq}))",
               "(col4 == 'something')"
              )).format(col2_neq=-some_value-1, col3_neq=-another_value-1)]
```

This is similar to your solution, but differs in two ways:

1. The `format` is in the end so it would be easier to read the first four rows without interruption.
2. I used named substitutions (`{col2_neq}` and `{col3_neq}` instead of two `{}`) so that the last line will be readable.